# How to keep the score of a game while using loops and have an end game score after quitting

Tags: loops

As you can see I am a beginner. I am looking for help on getting the score updated for every round the user dose. I also want to get a total for when the user quits the game. I am having problems with the var being used outside the loop. I have no idea on how to add the score together as well. Thank you for your time!
I am using Kotlin

```
fun main() 

              } else if () {
 while () {
var win = 0
var losses = 0
var ties = 0

println(" Win = $win")
println(" Losses = $losses")
println(" Ties = $ties")
 }
}
```

Comment: "I am having problems " is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: Thank you for the information I will try to shorten the code I publish from now on if I can think of a way. The problem I have is updating the score for every round the user plays. It will only give the results for the round that has been played. What I am trying to do is update the status board for every round that is played and show the total results at the end of every round in Wins, Losses, and Ties. When the user quits I want to show the total results in Wins, Losses, and Ties.

Comment: Figured it out thanks

Answer (score 1):

The vars for stats need to be declared outside the while brackets to allow the var to be accessible outside the loop. Instead of

```
} else if () {
 while () {
var win = 0
var losses = 0
var ties = 0

println(" Win = $win")
println(" Losses = $losses")
println(" Ties = $ties")
 }
}
```

Should be

```
} else if () {
 var win = 0
var losses = 0
var ties = 0

while () {

}

println(" Win = $win")
println(" Losses = $losses")
println(" Ties = $ties")
}
```

Comment: Good job finding the answer by yourself! Nice work!